# Flask/SQLAlchemy error: TypeError: Incompatible collection type: [model] is not list-like

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

i have nasty problem in very simple application. I try many different ways, but still cant figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I use **Flask** + **flask.ext.sqlalchemy**, also my model relationship is **many-to-many**.

```
authorship = db.Table('authorship',
    db.Column('author_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('author.id')),
    db.Column('book_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('book.id'))
)


class Book(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(), unique=False)

    authors = db.relationship('Author', secondary=authorship, backref=db.backref('books', lazy='dynamic'))

    def __init__(self, title, description, authors):
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        self.authors = authors

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.title


class Author(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
```

No matter how i change my models and play with relationship i still have same error (Author or other model):

```
TypeError: Incompatible collection type: Author is not list-like
```

Error shows up when i try to add new book.

I use these models with WTForms:

```
@app.route('/add_book', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_book():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        abort(401)
    form = AddBookForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        a = Author(form.author.data)
        b = Book(form.title.data, form.description.data, a)
        db.session.add(b)
        flash("book added")
    return render_template('add_book.html', form=form)
```

Comment: I think you should define your relationship like: `authors = db.relationship('Author', secondary=authorship, backref='books')` according to the docs (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html#many-to-many

Comment: thank, i think i try that, but i can try it again.

Comment: can you add an example of code when you use the models?

Comment: i use these models with WTForms, like that. (added in question)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken that's a M2M relation Books - Authors, so instead of

```
b = Book(form.title.data, form.description.data, a)
```

you should probably do

```
b = Book(form.title.data, form.description.data, [a])
```

as it expects a list and you've given it just one object.